# Is $\Bbb R^2$ a subspace of the complex vector space $\Bbb C^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am attempting to illustrate whether or not $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$. Originally my intuition said yes, because we can write any real number as a complex number where $b=0$, ie we can write $2 \in \mathbb{R}$ as $2=2+0i$.

However, this is apparently incorrect, and the example in my book shows that this would suggest that $i(1,1) = (i,i) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and thereby yielding a contradiction.

I guess I don't understand the above argument. Is it because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not closed under multiplication when we consider a scalar $a \in \mathbb{F}^2,$ where $\mathbb{F}$ represents a field of $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your field. If $\Bbb F=\Bbb R$ then $\Bbb R^2$ is indeed a subspace. If $\Bbb F=\Bbb C$ then $\Bbb R^2$ is NOT a subspace.

Comment: That was basically my question. The specific problem I was working on didn't mention it, but in general we have been using that $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$. If so, I understand it. I guess I was just wondering if anyone knew what the general convention was but your answer leads me to believe that their isn't one and it's a case by case basis.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, $\Bbb C^2$ can be assumed a vector space over $\Bbb C$. @agra94

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{F}^2$ can generally be assumed to mean a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The problem statement does also mention "complex vector space" which usually means considering the scalar field to be $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

To say that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-subspace of the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$ implies that
\begin{equation}
  \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{C}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2, \quad \alpha \cdot x \in \mathbb{R}^2
\end{equation}
since a vector space must contain the result of any of its vectors multiplied by any of the scalars.

With $\alpha = i$ and $x = (1, 1)$ we find a vector $\alpha \cdot x = (i, i)$ which is not an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Okay, so the scalar "a" that we are dealing with will always be a part of the larger vector space? So if we are trying to determine whether or not some set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we will be using a scalar $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: A vector space has 2 parts: one is the field of scalars, the other is the group of vectors. They are often different. The scalar $\alpha$ in your question is an element of the field $\mathbb{C}$. The expression "complex vector space $X$" means "the vectors are the elements of $X$ and the scalars the elements of $\mathbb{C}$". A subspace of a vector space has the same field of scalars as the vector space itself. The question considers $\mathbb{R}^2$ (vectors) with $\mathbb{C}$ (scalars), on one hand, and $\mathbb{C}^2$ (vectors) with $\mathbb{C}$ (scalars) on the other.